# Another set of eyes: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've counted, checked my commas, and went over the whole thing again but I still can't find what is causing this error. It is telling me that I'm trying to put more information in than I've given column names for, but I have 29 columns and 29 values. There are no missing commas that I can see.

Could someone give this a glance over and see if there is anything that I'm missing?

```
$query = <<<EOD

insert into roster

 (conference, regtime, participanttype_id, category_id, title, 

  firstname, lastname, badgename, jobtitle, department, 

  organization, address1, address2, address3, city, 

  state, country, postal, email, phone, 

  fax, paytype, feedue, f01, yn01, 

  yn02, yn03, yn04, other) 

 values 

 ('event1023', now(), $sfund_partictype_id, $sfund_category_id, '$title', 

 '$firstname', '$lastname', '$badgename', '$jobtitle', '$deptname', 

 '$organization', '$address1', '$address2', '$address3', '$city', 

 '$state', '$country', '$postal', '$email', '$phone', 

 '$fax', '$paytype', $feedue, '$wedsession', '$yn01', 

 '$yn02', '$yn03', '$yn04', '$other')

  EOD;
```

ETA: I've spaced this out like this because past critiques of my posts suggest that I should do so. It's not like this in my code though.

ETA #2: Here's the weird thing. The values go into the database perfectly. but it still returns this (and also made me realize that EEK MY CODE IS SHOWING EXACT ERRORS, so as an aside, yes I will fix that before it goes live):

Query failed:

```
insert into roster 

(conference, regtime, participanttype_id, category_id, title, 
firstname, lastname, badgename, jobtitle, department, 
organization, address1, address2, address3, city, 
state, country, postal, email, phone, 
fax, paytype, feedue, f01, yn01, 
yn02, yn03, yn04, other) 

values 

('event1023', now(), 3, 14, 'Ms',
'Jane','Smith','Jane Smith', 'Developer', 'my dept',
'my organization', 'my address', '','','my city',
'NC','United States','55555','me@email.edu','555-555-5555',
'', 'CHECK', 225, '2', '1',
'0', '1', '0', 'n/a')
```

`Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: s/EOD;/;EOD/ ??? (dont know if mysql requires semicolons)

Comment: I'm thinking it could be something to do with the call to now() ? I think you should assign this to a variable outside of this query and then use $now (or whatever) to insert it. The parentheses are probably confusing it. (Not an SQL Guru at all so didn't post an answer)

Comment: whats the output of $query as a variable (just to show it with values in)

Comment: I notice that in the error message, you are missing a field. Only 'my_address' and "," where $address1, $address2, and $address3 would be.

Comment: 'my address', '','',  :it's all there I think?

Comment: I ran a test of that SQL, it runs just fine. If your statement is inserting a row into the table, then its not this statement throwing the exception. Make sure you don't have an `AFTER INSERT`  trigger on this table. (If it's not this SQL that's throwing the exception, then it's got to be some other SQL statement, and a TRIGGER is the most likely suspect.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll keep troubleshooting (and will post when I figure it out).

Comment: I suspect that it is not your INSERT statement that is causing the exception, but rather, another statement. I recommend you check for an AFTER INSERT trigger on the `roster` table.  (Is there a "roster change history" table which is maintained by triggers, and does it use an `INSERT INTO roster_log SELECT * FROM roster`.  (My answer is updated with this same info.)

Comment: @mschocobo: you report (as a comment to an answer) that the columns yn01,yn02,yn03 and yn04 are defined as BIT(1) DEFAULT 0.  Note that both of the character string you provide as literals ('0' and '1') will set the BIT(1) value to `b'1'`. You probably want to specify e.g. `b'1'`, `b'0'` as values in the query text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My lesson for the week: go check with IT to make sure that there isn't something else happening on a more global basis...don't just assume your code is incorrect.

Thank you for all trying to help me figure this out- next time I will call the IT guys instead of troubleshooting for far too long.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost certainly due to the lack of variable escaping.  There are two things I would suggest:

First, make sure anything that could possibly have a single-quote in it has been run through an escaping function, or barring that, something to just double each one.  I don't think that's leading to your problem, though, since someone'd have to have exactly "','" in a value.

More likely would be if $feedue has a comma in it.  That would split the value into two numbers, so it would still be valid -- just not what you want.  Your DB should automatically cast a string to a number (but not vice versa), so the easiest thing to try is putting quotes around that value as well.

Comment: Except this code was working perfectly before I was asked to add in the last few pieces- yn01,yn02,yn03,yn04 and other. I set the yn01-yn04 to be bit(1) with default as 0 (no) unless they check yes (1). Then, other is varchar. Since it worked before I added those things I would have to think that it was the addition of those things that is causing my error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that any of the string values have ' (quotes) in them? this would case it..

i.e. value of $postal contained a ' this would end it and make it think there is a new value, or a surname like, O'Neil... etc etc

In other words... validate the string values with PDO (you should be using this anyway m ysql_/mysqli_ commands are dated and can leat to all sorts of bad code and unsafe code) OR at least mysql_real_escape_string or any methods to ensure single quotes are not in the values :)

Answer (score 0):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

You are including "unsafe" strings in your query text. Print the contents of $query, after the assignment.  You'll see the problem then.

Consider the contents of $query when, for example:

```
$title = "Courage','Fear";
```

I recommend you use the `mysql_real_escape_string` function to avoid SQL injection.

---

**EDIT:** based on further information provided by OP

OP reports that strings provided in SQL text are properly escaped, and OP provides example query text produced.

OP reports that after code is executed, the row is found to be inserted to database. So, we can be pretty sure that it's NOT this statement that is throwing the exception. It must be some other statement.

OP also reports that this was working BEFORE he added columns to the table.

Given the SQL text you added to your question, I ran a test, it runs just fine for me.

So, I'm pretty sure that it's not the INSERT statement you show here, but some OTHER statement that is throwing the exception. Do you happen to have an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on this table?

Comment: Oh I have this for that: 

foreach ($_POST as $name => $val)$$name = trim(escapeString($val));